# Let's Encrypt with Docker and Traefik: cannot get certificate to work. And timeout error in Chrome

Tags: docker, nginx, drupal, traefik, lets-encrypt

I cannot get Let's Encrypt certificate to work with Traefik and Nginx.

I followed a few tutorials about how to set up Let's Encrypt with Nginx, including:
https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-tls/

After many tries and research I cannot find the way to make it work and this message keeps poping up in the logs:

> my_drupal10_project_traefik  | time="2023-06-03T13:33:09Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."
> my_drupal10_project_traefik  | time="2023-06-03T13:33:34Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains "domeuropa.fr": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [domeuropa.fr]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[domeuropa.fr] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: 2a01:4f8:c012:da33::: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)\n" rule="Host(`domeuropa.fr`)" providerName=myresolver.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" routerName=my_drupal10_project_nginx@docker

When I log into https://domeuropa.fr/, I either have :

- When using Firefox, a security warning, as if the certificate is self-signed
- When using Chrome (or Chromium), a timeout error

I cannot get a way around that, that is why I am asking for help.

Current configuration :

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    volumes:
#      - ./mariadb-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # Place init .sql file(s) here.
      - /var/lib/drupal-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql # Use bind mount

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      SSMTP_MAILHUB: mailhog:1025
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: '"/usr/bin/dos2unix -u | /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t -f"'
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html:cached

  crond:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_crond"
    environment:
      CRONTAB: "0 * * * * drush -r /var/www/html/web cron"
    command: sudo -E crond -f -d 0
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html:cached

  nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
    - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html:cached
## Alternative for macOS users: Mutagen https://wodby.com/docs/stacks/drupal/local#docker-for-mac
#    - drupal:/var/www/html
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.rule=Host(`${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.entrypoints=web,websecure"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.tls=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog"
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.services.${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog.loadbalancer.server.port=8025"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog.rule=Host(`mailhog.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"

  node:
    image: wodby/node:$NODE_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_node"
    working_dir: /var/www/html/web/themes/custom/DomEuropa_barrio_sass
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.services.${PROJECT_NAME}_node.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_node.rule=Host(`node.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"
    expose:
    - "3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    command: sh -c 'cd /var/www/html/web/themes/custom/DomEuropa_barrio_sass && 
      npm init --yes && npm install --global gulp-cli && npm install --save-dev gulp && npm install && gulp'

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.10.1"
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=false"
      - "--api.dashboard=false"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=vincent@domeuropa.fr"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

volumes:
## For macOS users (Mutagen)
#  drupal:
# For Xdebug profiler
  files:
```

Important values from .env file:

```
PROJECT_NAME=my_drupal10_project
PROJECT_BASE_URL=domeuropa.fr
PROJECT_PORT=80
```

Comment: Problem comes from IPv6

After removing AAAA record from the DNS zone it is working

. Of course this is just a temporary solution, as it is needed to find the root cause of this IPv6 issue